Error ‘Error saving test devices: Something went wrong’ when adding a test device to A/B test
When trying to add a test device to Firebase A/B test, the error ‘[Error saving test devices: Something went wrong]

Tested with several user tokens. Firebase console perceives the tokens themselves as correct.
Browser console [returns 500 error]

, without giving details.
I would be grateful for help to figure out how to fix this.

No worry @Ivan I did add the photos to your post as it should be.
